# How to sort an array of Images

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, nsmutablearray

How to sort an NSMutableArray of images, based on the images' height?
Do I need to find the height of each image and add it in order, or is there an easier way?

Comment: Well, you *could* study the documentation for NSArray and NSMutableArray and pick out one of the several methods that can do this.  Or you could ask someone else to do your work for you.

Comment: I think that's a little unfair. He's not asking for a generic method to sort an array; he's asking for a way to sort an array of images based on their properties, which will not be covered in the docs for NSMutableArray.

Comment: @davidf2281 -- How is it not covered?  Simplest for a novice to understand is sortedArrayUsingFunction, since that uses a simple C-like function to do the "dirty work".  But there are six sort functions for NSArray, and five for NSMutableArray, so he has many to choose from.  The hardest part is picking one out.

Comment: It's not covered because there's no `sortArrayOfImagesByImageHeight` method on `NSMutableArray`. But yes, I agree it's not particularly hard to figure it out.

Comment: @davidf2281 - That's what is referred to as "programming".

Comment: @HotLicks - ...and giving folk assistance with "programming" problems is what stackoverflow was for, last time I looked.

Comment: @davidf2281 - But not until they've made a reasonable attempt to solve the programming problem themselves.  And fundamental to this is being able to state what the problem is.

Comment: How is this off topic?
And also I have mentioned in the question, the way I was going to solve this issue, just wanted to find out, if there was a more elegant, easier, optimized way to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if it's an array of UIImage objects your can use this :

```
NSArray * sortedArray = [source sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2){

        UIImage *t1 = (UIImage *)obj1;
        UIImage *t2 = (UIImage *)obj2;

if (t1.size.height > t2.size.height)
return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
else
return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
}];
```

Comment: What about `NSOrderedSame` ...?

Comment: Remark: You can *remove all type casts* if you declare the block as `^NSComparisonResult(UIImage *t1, UIImage *t2)` .